# Python 3.x: Avoid overwriting of same methods from different inherited classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have the following problem:

I tried to create a class inheriting from two other classes which have internal `__setitem__` methods each. As part of the `featuresB` initialization I want to call a `createFeaturesB` function which creates content for that class. Unfortunately the call of `__setitem__` is referring to `featuresA.__setitem__` as one can see from the output of the two print statements in the end.

```
class featuresA():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dictA      = dict()
        return
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dictA[key] = value
        return

class featuresB():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dictB      = dict()
        self.createFeaturesB()
        return
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dictB[key] = value
        return
    def createFeaturesB(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self[i] = i**2
        return

class C(featuresA, featuresB):
    def __init__(self):
        featuresA.__init__(self)
        featuresB.__init__(self)
        return

c = C()
print(c._dictB) #returns: {}
print(c._dictA) #returns: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}
```

How can I avoid the overwrite of the two methods?

Comment: You can explicitly set the method you want `__setitem__ = featuresB.__setitem__`, you can switch the order of the parents so `featuresB` comes first in the MRO `class C(featuresB, featuresA):`, or you can just not inherit from `featuresA` at all.

Comment: Thanks. The first solution is what I will do for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes good to first consider if you built your inheritance diagram correctly. In this case, reversing your inheritance order fixes it.

```
class C(featuresB, featuresA): # Reverse the inheritance order
    def __init__(self):
        featuresA.__init__(self)
        featuresB.__init__(self)

c = C()
c._dictB # {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}
c._dictA # {}
```

Although in general, having multiple inheritance from classes which have not been implemented to support it is problematic. You might want to update `featuresA` to use `super`.

```
class featuresA():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dictA      = dict()
        super().__init__()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dictA[key] = value
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

class featuresB():
    def __init__(self):
        self._dictB      = dict()
        self.createFeaturesB()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dictB[key] = value

    def createFeaturesB(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self[i] = i**2

class C(featuresA, featuresB):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

c = C()
c._dictB # {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}
c._dictA # {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}
```

In more complex cases where you would want to cherry-pick certain methods from each class, then you would need to rebuild your class diagram, *i.e.* rewrite your bases classes. Multiple inheritance is a powerful tool, but it is not magic. It delegates some responsibility to the developper.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed overview! I'm quite certain that you're absolutely right with your annotations... I'm still not happy with my class diagram. :/ As long as I have not figured out how to change it into a better thing, I'll stick with the messy `featuresB.__setitem__` solution although I'm not really happy with it.